# How to stop checking when a string has empty index

Tags: c++, string

```
/* Write a program that would mix-and-merge two given strings (s1 and s2) into string s3 as follows:
 first character of s1, first character of s2, second character of s1, second character of s2, etc. */
```

But the problem with my code is: that if i type for s1 `"John"` and then for s2 `"Stevens"`
Result will be = `JSothenv e n s.`

How do i fix the spaces that are left after one of the strings ends?

The way i thought i would fix it is i would check with the ifs i have below in the for loop To see if the index is null or '\0' but that doesn't work as the string holds random values after the string ends.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1, s2; 
    string s3;
    int i; // For index
    int j = 0; // For second index and loop checking

    cout << "Type first string: ";
    getline(cin, s1);
    cout << "Type second string: ";
    getline(cin, s2);

    s3.resize(s1.size() + s2.size() + 100); // The + 100 is used so we have space for all the characters. The + 100 is not needed if i fix my problem.

    for(i = 0; j <= s1.size(); i += 2)
    {
        if(s1[j] == null) // With what do i check it?
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            s3[i] = s1[j];
            ++j;
        }
    }

    j = 0;

    for(i = 1; j <= s2.size(); i += 2)
    {
        if(s2[j] == null)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
        s3[i] = s2[j];
        }
        ++j;
    }

    for( i = 0; i <= s3.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << s3[i];  
    }

    return 0;
```

Comment: Your first paragraph is really confusing.  Please re-read it and try to think about how to make it clearer.  Providing a thorough set of example inputs and outputs would help.

Comment: Maybe you meant to say:  "Given two input strings, I would like to produce a third string made by interleaving the characters of the input strings.  For example, given "DOG" and "octopus", I would want to produce..."

Comment: Ok thanks i will do so :) Edit is it better now?

Comment: In your example you expect `JSothenvens`?

Comment: Yes. But also if the user uses spaces i want them shown. But only if the user uses spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    string s1, s2, s3;

    int i,j,k;
    cout << "Type first string: ";
    getline(cin, s1);
    cout << "Type second string: ";
    getline(cin, s2);
    s3.resize(s1.size()+s2.size());

    for(i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; j < s1.size() && k < s2.size(); i++) {
        if(i & 1) {
            s3[i] = s2[k++];
        } else {
            s3[i] = s1[j++];
        }
    }
    if(j == s1.size()) {
        while(k < s2.size()) {
            s3[i++] = s2[k++];
        }
    } else {
        while(j < s1.size()) {
            s3[i++] = s1[j++];
        }
    }

    cout << s3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works my friend but can you explain a bit how it works does cause i am confused

Comment: The for loop is basically interleaving `s1` and `s2` until one of them comes to end. Then the if statement simply add the remaining part to `s3`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit this part? if `(i & 1)`

Comment: It's the same as `if(i%2 == 1)`.

Comment: When i is odd, add `s2` to `s3`; when i is even, add `s1` to `s3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the code after `getline` with this:

```
  string::const_iterator i1 = s1.begin(), i2 = s2.begin();
  bool useFirst = true;

  while (i1 != s1.end() || i2 != s2.end())
  {
    if (useFirst && i1 != s1.end())
    {
      s3.push_back(*i1++);
    }
    else if (i2 != s2.end())
    {
      s3.push_back(*i2++);
    }

    useFirst = !useFirst; // switch over for next iteration
  }

  cout << s3 << endl;
```

It's a bit simpler, and basically iterates alternately over the two strings until they're both exhausted.

Comment: Thanks this works now but the result is a bit weird. Like instead of having result `JSothenv e n s` i have result:            JSothenv e n s                       like there are many spaces in the beginning. Edit stack overflow will not let me display it but in the second result there are many spaces in the begging before correct output `JSothenv e n s` is shown.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple to write a generic `interleave` algorithm that iterates over both ranges once:

```
template<typename InputIterator1, typename InputIterator2, typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator interleave(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 end1,
                          InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 end2,
                          OutputIterator out)
{
  while(first1 != end1 && first2 != end2)
  {
    out = *first1;
    out = *first2;
    ++first1;
    ++first2;
  }
  // copy remaining elements from both ranges
  while(first1 != end1)
  {
    out = *first1;
    ++first1;
  }
  while(first2 != end2)
  {
    out = *first2;
    ++first2;
  }
  return out;
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6451b2c073686e54). Usage is like `std::set_merge`:

```
  interleave(begin(s1), end(s1),
             begin(s2), end(s2),
             std::back_inserter(result));
```

It iterates over both ranges until one runs out, then copies the remaining elements in both ranges. Iterates once over both containers and has one double end check I couldn't get rid of without assuming one range to be larger than the other. Can handle two different containers now

Comment: qualifying `std::begin` and `std::end` feels a bit like an anti-pattern to me. I'd say using free-function begin/end should use ADL like ranged-for. Also, I'd write `while` loops consistently (the loops are all structurally identical). Finally, you'll want to allow for mixed input ranges.

Comment: @sehe Done. Never thought of it (ADL) that way. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Here's my suggested version http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce939199348423ee (I know it might doing more comparisons, potentially, but I'd say let the compiler optimize/worry about optimizing after profiling). See how it returns the output iterator (convention) and it can take different iterator types